# Get proper file notification using SCEvents (FSEvents wrapper )?

Tags: objective-c, macos, fsevents

I had implemented file watcher part using SCEvents : https://github.com/mz2/SCEvents

Its notifying me changed in the form of event_id, event_path and event_flags. But how should I get information which event is raise. Its not giving any details like File created event occurs, File Renamed event occur etc.

How should i get proper information about which event is raised?

Please provide guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SCEventFlags`.

```
if ((event.eventFlags & SCEventStreamEventFlagItemCreated) != 0)
{
//ItemCreated
}
```